# Can't add form tag into the table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

When I add form tag into the table my input field are hiding and I'm getting warning like this:

```
index.js:1446 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>.

index.js:1446 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>.
```

This is my code:

```html
<Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>color</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>manufactureDate</th>
      <th>quantity</th>
      <th>Expiry Date</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <form>
      <div>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="id" value={this.state.id} disabled />
          </td>

          <td>
            <input type="text" name="color" ref="color" defaultValue={this.state.color} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="size" ref="size" defaultValue={this.state.size} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="date" name="manufacturedate" ref="manufacturedate" defaultValue={this.state.manufactureDate} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" ref="quantity" defaultValue={this.state.quantity} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="date" name="expirydate" ref="expirydate" defaultValue={this.state.expiryDate} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <select ref="option" onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option value={this.state.productId}>
                {this.state.productName}
              </option>
              {this.state.products.map(option => (
              <option key={option.id} value={option.id} // onChange={this.setState.product.id}>
                {option.name}
              </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>{this.getBtn()}</td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

I'm doing add, update and delete all the things into the table. When I validate that field I need a form tag. Can anyone help to me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not semantic HTML. The only permitted element for `tbody` is `tr`. HTML has a strict set of rules relating to which tags can appear where. A lot of browsers don't enforce those rules, but your IDE will.

Using tables to layout your form is really not a good idea anyway. If you use a table to create your layout it will not always resize properly with your screen. Instead of using a table you can used divs with css flexbox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Divs allow flow content so you can put a form inside a div and forms also allow flow content, so you can put divs inside forms.

Flexbox gives good cross browser support and makes it relatively easy to create grid layouts that are responsive.

Comment: @MajutharanMajutharan 
A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr.

Comment: now i'm clearly understand @Leon but i need to create a smart table to add, edit and delete then i want to validate that fields. What can I do?

Comment: Please refrain from linking w3schools as a resource. Learn more [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)